# Expand/Collapse works only for the first item

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create an accordion/panel with expand/collapse. All the data from model are printed correctly, the only issue I get is that collapse/expand work for the first item. How can I implement it for each item?

my code:

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <?php
    $html_ret = '

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls=".collapse">
                    <b>%s</b> (%s)
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                %s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    foreach($arr_table_content as $row)
    {
        echo sprintf($html_ret, $row['TrainingName'],$row['TrType'],$row['Tr_description']);
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: The problem is that you use the `collapseOne` id and other id's multiple times. You should make sure that all id's are only used once.

Comment: Make a variable `$i` place it in the id attribute (remember to initialise the variable). and increment the `$i` variable with each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the rest panel have the same ID as the first panel `#collapseOne`, try to concatinate an increment number with the id, ex:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    <?php
    $html_ret = '

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne%u" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls=".collapse">
                    <b>%s</b> (%s)
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne%u" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                %s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    $counter = 1;
    foreach($arr_table_content as $row)
    {
        echo sprintf($html_ret,$counter,$row['TrainingName'],$row['TrType'],$counter,$row['Tr_description']);
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem comes from the fact that all your panel-headings have the same `id="headingOne"`. Try setting a dynamic ID in your foreach loop (same thing for your `panel-collapse`)